# Is this the correct way to get information from forign-key model Django

Tags: python, django

In the model declaration, I make property:

```
@property
    def author(self):
    book_id = getattr(self, 'book_id')

    book = Book.objects.get(id=book_id)
    author_id = getattr(book, 'author_id')

    author = Author.objects.get(id=author_id)
    author_name = getattr(author, 'first_name')

    return author_name
```

To get data on the front.
It works. But how is this possible and how can it be done better?

Comment: I do not know from your question to which class corresponds `self`. However, to get the first name of the author, you can simplify the last five lines of the function as `return Book.objects.get(id=book_id).author.first_name`. You are overusing 'getattr' function when it is not needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to quick get relative data by forign-key from another model, that apply to attribute of object model by chain.

```
class BookInstance(models.Model):
   @property
   def author(self):
      if self.book_id and self.book.author_id:
           return self.book.author.first_name
```

=

```
class BookInstance(models.Model):
    @property
    def author(self):
    book_id = getattr(self, 'book_id')

    book = Book.objects.get(id=book_id)
    author_id = getattr(book, 'author_id')

    author = Author.objects.get(id=author_id)
    author_name = getattr(author, 'first_name')

    return author_name
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.